# Update three-level nested django model using serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to update one of my models (which is a nested model - three level actually as you can see below) and I am getting the following error:

> AssertionError: The .update() method does not support writable nestedfields by default. Write an explicit .update() method for serializer SystemSettingsSerializer, or set read_only=True on nested serializer fields.

All day I have been reading about nested models and nested serializers, trying to add `update` and `create` methods setting fields as `read_only=True` but no matter what I did, it just didn't work :( :(

These are my models:

```
class SystemSettings(models.Model):
    # ... some fields


class Components(models.Model):
    settings = models.ForeignKey(SystemSettings, related_name="Components")


class SysComponent(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstarct = True

    index = models.PositiveIntegerField(primery_key=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    component = NotImplemented


class Foo(SysComponent):
    component = models.ForeignKey(Components, related_name="Foo")


class Bar(SysComponent):
    component = models.ForeignKey(Components, related_name="Bar")
    task_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

and serializers:

```
class SystemSettingsSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    Components = ComponentsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = SystemSettings
        fields = [# some fields,
                  Components]


class ComponentsSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    Foo = FooSerializer(many=True)
    Bar = BarSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Components
        fields = ['Foo',
                  'Bar']                  


class FooSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo


class BarSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Bar
```

My logic is the following:
I am fetching the `SystemSettings` via `GET` and display it in a form.
The user changes it as much as he want and by clicking submit I send it back via `PUT`.

As I said I am getting the error above after clicking submit.
Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT: I am using django 1.7.8 by the way**